# Row value in index formula

Tags: excel, indexing, row

I'm using following formula:

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$E$2:$T$75000,SMALL(IF(Data!$E$2:$T$75000='Master Data Analysis'!K22,ROW(Data!$E$2:$T$75000)),ROW(1:1))-1,16),""))
```

is there any chance to make this part **ROW(Data!1:1)** being dependent on another cell.

So lets say if desired cell says `1`, than `Row(1:1)`, however if that cell says `3`, it will say `Row(3:3)`.

Comment: If the cell you're looking at is `A1` then `INDIRECT("Data1!"&A1&":"&A1)` will return the row in sheet Data1 specified in the cell.

Comment: All you need to do is replace `Row(1:1)` with the cell reference.  `ROW(3:3)` --> `3`.  So if your cell contains a `3` ...

Answer (score 0):

What I believe Phylogenesis was trying to say is not that you should change ROW with INDIRECT, but make a `=ROW(INDIRECT("Data!"&A1&":"&A1))` reference there (if the cell, where the row number is, is A1 (your "desired cell"))

Comment: Not sure how is that not working. I just put that in my Excel and that formula (alone, without the rest of your code) is working well.

Comment: My apology heaton123, it does work. I must have made a type somewhere the first time I tried it. thank you for your help